# Result of function vs loop

Tags: python, loops, tuples

My first script doesn't return the result of the whole input list, and the second one doesnt return iterable tuple. Any advice?

```
input= [0.1, 0.2]
def newvalue():
    for i in input:
        value=integrate.quad(lambda i:(np.exp(-i))/i,i,np.inf)
        return value[0]
print(newvalue()) #1.8229239584193715
```

If I use the following script it does the work and it prints all the values which results from the input list, but the problem with this script that I can't iterate through the calculated values.

```
for i in input:
    value = integrate.quad(lambda i: (np.exp(-i)) / i, i, np.inf)
    print(value[0]) #1.8229239584193715
                    #1.2226505441838773
```

Comment: You need to build up an array and return it after the for loop ends.

Comment: `return` breaks loop.

Comment: Are you looking for `yield`  ? instead of breaking the loop, it would give you the next value at each call, look into `generators`, ... also you should pass the "input" as parameter and not use it as global

Answer (score 4):

As said in the comments, you need to create a loop and append the values inside just like so:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

input_= [0.1, 0.2]

def newvalue():
    values = []
    for i in input_:
        value=integrate.quad(lambda i:(np.exp(-i))/i,i,np.inf)
        values.append(value[0])
    return values

print(newvalue()) #[1.8229239584193715, 1.2226505441838773]
```

Comment: `input_` appears clearly to be, well, *input* to the newvalue function, and as such should probably be a parameter, not a global var.

Comment: I totally agree... I always try to fix the problem with the least amount of changes.

Answer (score 2):

The first script only provides one value because you have a `return` in the loop — the loop doesn’t continue after that.

There are two typical ways to handle this situation. The first is to create an empty array before your loop, add each result to the array during the loop, and return that results array after the loop. That approach is ok if the number of values / loops is small, i.e. you don’t want to build up a 10,000,000 element array.

If the number of values / loops is bigger, or if your outer function may not need all the values, use a `yield` in place of your return. That allows the called function to generate each value as needed when called from an outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

After calling `return` statements the function does not continue and all information is lost that has not been either returned or is not referenced by a variable outside the function scope.

The answer from Anwarvic should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Your function should not take it's argument from a global variable. 
You can define your function so that it accepts one value, and returns the caluclated result for this value.

```
def newvalue(input):
    value=integrate.quad(lambda i:(np.exp(-i))/i,i,np.inf)
    return value
```

You can then query it in a few different fashions :

1. In a loop

```
for i in [0.1, 0.2]:
    print(newvalue(i))
```

2. Or via list comprehension :

```
inputs = [0.1,0.2]
answers = [newvalue(i) for i in inputs]

print(answers)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first example simply replace the command

```
return value[0]
```

with

```
yield value[0]
```

Then you may use a `newvalue()` in these forms, for example:

1. `list(newvalue())`  to obtain a list of all calculated values,
2. `for i in newvalue():` to iterate through calculated values.